# Get seconds remaining, refresh it every second and display it in format minutes:seconds

Tags: javascript, php

here is my code : https://hastebin.com/azitobicas.xml

I would like to get the remaining time (it works, it return me it in seconds).

I would like to show this time in format minutes:seconds (i:s), and it must be refreshed every seconds, I do it in Javascript.

As you can see in my code, I get the remaining time from javascript in PHP with `$remain = "<span id='remaining'></span>";` but the problem is to display it in the format minutes:seconds (i:s), I try to use gmdate (`echo gmdate("i:s", $remain);`) but it's not working, nothing is displayed, and I don't find/know why.

PS: It's working with for example `$remain = 500;`

Thanks.

Comment: please vote up the approved answer to persons have Motivation to help other. its very impotent friend ;-)

Comment: I did it :) Didn't had enough rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var count = <?php echo $rowTime - $spent; ?>;
var counter = setInterval(function(){ 
    remaining(); 
}, 1000);
function remaining(){
    var minute = parseInt(count / 60)
    var second = count % 60;
    document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute 
    + ':' + (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
    count--;
    if(count == 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
        document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML = "<div id='get_refreshbutton' class='col-md-14' style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;'><button name='refreshBtn' onclick='window.location.reload()' class='btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg' style='font-size: 14pt;'><i class='fa fa-refresh' aria-hidden='true'></i> 5 MINUTES SPENT, YOU CAN REFRESH</button></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Working, thanks a lot ! But how can i do to show, instead of "2:3" (for example) : "02:03" ? Thanks.

Comment: I accepted it, but can you answer to my question, please ?

Comment: I did it :) Didn't had enough rep

Comment: I knew ;-) Thank you